# Why is my xAxis not sorting in d3?

Tags: sorting, d3.js, graph

Yesterday I posted a question about a bar graph that I didn't know how to sort in alphabetical order. @Mark_M very kindly answered and provided me whith a good solution that normally should perfectly work.

Here is the snippet:

```
var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale).tickSize(0)

var sortBars = function() {
    // Change domain based on sorted data
    xScale.domain(data.sort(function(a, b) {
        return  d3.ascending(a.Region, b.Region);
        })
        .map(function(d) {return d.Region})
    )

    // Redraw Rects with new position
    svg.selectAll("rect")
      .transition()
      .duration(1000)
      .attr("x", function(d, i) {return xScale(d.Region)})

    // Redraw x Axis
    axeX.transition()
    .duration(1000)
    .call(xAxis)
```

The `"rect"` are indeed sorting, however the x Axis (here called `axeX`) doesn't change at all. It seems that the calling of `xAxis` (last line) doesn't work.

Any idea of what's going on here ?

Here is the full code, the sorting part is at the very end:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset = "utf-8">
        <title>D3 Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <style>
        div.tooltip {position: absolute;            
                     text-align: center;            
                     width: none;                   
                     height: none;                  
                     padding: none;             
                     font: 12px futura;
                     color: thistle;        
                     background: none;  
                     border: 0px;       
                     border-radius: 8px;            
                     pointer-events: none;}

        svg {background-color: none;}


        .tooltip {font: 10px futura;
                  color: thistle;}


        .axisX line{stroke: white;}
        .axisX path{stroke: white;}
        .axisX text{fill: black;}  

        .axisY line{stroke: black;}
        .axisY path{stroke: white;}


        .horizontalGrid line {stroke: lightgrey;
                              stroke-opacity: 0;
                              shape-rendering: crispEdges;}
        .horizontalGrid path {stroke-width: 0;}



        </style>
        <script type ="text/javascript" src = d3/d3.js></script>
        <script>

        //Variables; dimensions du canevas
        var margin = {top: 40, right: 20, bottom: 130, left: 120},
            svgWidth = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
            svgHeight = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom,
            barPadding = 2;

        //Variables: domaines de l'Axe X et Y
        var xScale = d3.scaleBand().range([0, svgWidth]).padding(0.1), //scaleBand pour des proportions
            yScale = d3.scaleLinear().range([svgHeight, 0]); //scaleLinear pour des unités (noms, lettres)

        //Variable: échelle de couleur divisée en 80 nuances entre deux couleurs
        var colorScale = d3.scaleLinear().domain([0,80]).range(["white",  "mediumturquoise"]);

        //Variable: création du canevas dans <body>
        var svg = d3.select("body")
                        .append("svg")
                        .attr("width", svgWidth + margin.left + margin.right)
                        .attr("height", svgHeight + margin.top + margin.bottom)
                        .append("g")
                        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

        //Variable: petit encadré qui apparait au passage de la souris
        var div = d3.select("body")
                        .append("div")
                        .attr("class", "tooltip")
                        .style("visibility", "hidden");

        var absoluteView = false




        //Variable: format des nombre lors de la transition de chargement des nombres -> https://github.com/d3/d3-format
        var format = d3.format("d"); //d = notation décimale arrondie aux entiers



        var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale).tickSize(0)


        //Biding: 
        d3.csv("/Users/daumardlouis/Desktop/geid3.csv", function(error, data) {if (error) throw error;

            data.forEach(function(d) {d.Classification = +d.Classification;});

            xScale.domain(data.map(function(d) {return d.Region}));
            yScale.domain([0, d3.max(data,function(d) {return d.Classification})]);

        var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale).tickSize(0) //marqueur d'échelle de taille 0


            //Définition des barres
            rect = svg.selectAll("rect")
                .data(data)
                .enter()
                .append("rect")
                .attr("x", function(d) {return xScale(d.Region)})
                .attr("width", svgWidth / data.length - barPadding)
                .attr("y", svgHeight) // écart de l'axe Y = hauteur du canevas SVG
                .attr("height", 0) // hauteur de départ des barres à 0 pour l'effet de transition
                .attr("fill", function (d) {return colorScale (d.Classification)})
                .style("opacity", 0.9)
                .on("mouseover",function(d) {d3.select(this).style("fill", "thistle").style("opacity", 0.5); // rempli de couleur la barre au passage de la souris
                                             div.transition() // affiche le div en 0.2 secondes avec opacité de .5
                                                .duration(200)
                                                .style("visibility", "hidden");
                                             div.html(d.Classification) // affiche une donnée ou un texte dans le div
                                                 .style("left", (d3.event.pageX - 50) + "px") 
                                                 .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 70) + "px"); // la hauteur du div par rapport à la souris (attention en html la hauteur est inversée)
                                             if(!absoluteView) {
                                                var xPos = parseFloat(d3.select(this).attr("x")) + 6;
                                                var yPos = parseFloat(d3.select(this).attr("y")) + 2;
                                                var height = parseFloat(d3.select(this).attr("height"));
                                                svg.append("text")
                                                .attr("x", xPos)
                                                .attr("y", yPos - 10)
                                                .attr("class", "tooltip")
                                                .text(d.Classification)
                                                .attr("fill", "thistle")};



                                    })

                .on("mouseout",function(d) {d3.select(this).transition().duration(150).style("fill", function (d) {return colorScale (d.Classification)}).style("opacity", 1); // renvoie la couleur initiale à la sortie de la souris
                                            div.transition() // faire disparaitre la div après .5 secondes
                                                .duration(200)
                                                .style("visibility", "hidden")
                                            svg.select(".tooltip").remove();

                                            });

            //Transition des barres (rect)
            rect.transition()
                .delay(1000)
                .ease(d3.easePoly)
                .duration(500)
                .attr("y", function(d) {return yScale(d.Classification)})
                .attr("height", function(d) {return svgHeight - yScale(d.Classification)}); 



            //Transition: effet de chargement progressif des nombres 
            var texte = svg.selectAll("text")
            .data(data)
            .enter()
            .append("text")
            .text(0) //texte à 0 au départ de la transition
            .attr("x", function(d, i) {return 8 + i * (svgWidth / data.length)})
            .attr("y", svgHeight) // commence à 0, cad à la hauteur du canevas 
            .attr("fill", "thistle")
            .attr("font-family", "futura")
            .attr("font-size", "10px")
            .transition()
            .delay(function(d,i){return i *30}) //ajouter un délai décalé pour chaque élément de data
            .ease(d3.easePoly)
            .duration(900)
            .attr("x", function(d, i) {return 8 + i * (svgWidth / data.length)})
            .attr("y", function(d) {return yScale(d.Classification) + (yScale(svgHeight) / 16) })
            .tween("text", function(d) {var that = d3.select(this),
                                            i = d3.interpolateNumber(that.text(), d.Classification); //donner une val de départ et de fin
                                            return function(t) {that.text(format(i(t)))}}) //retourne le texte au format défini plus haut
            .transition()
            .delay(function(d,i){return 500 + i * (-30)}) //delay de 500 + annulation du délai décalé
            .style("opacity", 0);


            //Axe X, son style et ses transitions
            var axeX = svg.append("g")
                .attr("transform", "translate(0," + svgHeight + ")")
                .call(xAxis) 
                .attr("class", "axisX") // récupère les indications de style de .axisX à l'interieur de la balise <style>. Utile pour changer la couleur de l'axe
                .selectAll("text")
                .attr("display", "true")
                .attr("font-size", 2)
                .attr("dx", "-4.8em")
                .attr("dy", "4.15em")
                .style("text-anchor", "end") //centre la fin du texte au milieu de chaque barre (rect)
                .attr("transform", "rotate(-65)"); //effectue une rotation de -65°


                axeX.transition()
                .duration(500)
                .delay(function(d,i){return i *30})
                .attr("font-family", "futura", "Bold")
                .attr("font-size", 10); //style de police de caractère




            //Axe Y, son style et ses transitions
            var axeY = svg.append("g")
                .attr("class", "axisY")
                .attr("transform", "translate(-5)")
                .transition()
                .duration(5000)
                .call(d3.axisLeft(yScale).tickSize(3))
                .selectAll("text")
                .attr("transform", "translate(-5)")
                .attr("font-family", "futura")
                .attr("fill", "thistle");   //couleur de police de caractère



            //Rajoute une légende à laxe Y
             svg.append("g")
             .append("text")
             .attr("font-family", "futura")
             .attr("font-size", 10)
             .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
             .attr("y", -48)
             .attr("x", -68)
             .style("text-anchor", "end")
             .text("");



            //Rajoute des lignes de fonds prolongeant l'axe Y
             svg.selectAll("axisY")
                .data(yScale)
                .enter()
                .append("line")
                .attr("class", "horizontalGrid")
                .attr("x1", 0)
                .attr("x2", svgWidth)
                .attr("y1", function(d){ return yScale(d);})
                .attr("y2", function(d){ return yScale(d);});





            //Title
            title = svg.append("text")
               .attr("x", (svgWidth / 2))
               .attr("y", 0 - (margin.top / 2))
               .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
               .attr("font-family", "futura")
               .style("fill", "#5a5a5a")
               .text("Nombre d'observations par régions");

                title.on("click", function () {sortBars()});



             // Sorting

            var sortBars = function() {xScale.domain(data.sort(function(a, b) 
                                     {return  d3.ascending(a.Region, b.Region)}).map(function(d) {return d.Region}))

           // Redraw Rects with new position
              svg.selectAll("rect")
                 .transition()
                 .duration(1000)
                 .attr("x", function(d, i) {return xScale(d.Region)})

           // Redraw x Axis
              axeX.transition()
                  .duration(1000)
                  .call(xAxis)

                                          }


       });
        </script>
    <body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure you are saving the correct thing to `axeX`. Because you've chained `selectAll("text")` to it, the `axeX` variable is referring to the text not the axis.

Try something like this instead:

```
   //Axe X, son style et ses transitions
    var axeX = svg.append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + svgHeight + ")")
        .call(xAxis)         
        .attr("class", "axisX") // récupère les indications de style de .axisX à l'interieur de la balise <style>. Utile pour changer la couleur de l'axe


    axeX.selectAll("text")
        .attr("display", "true")
        .attr("font-size", 2)
        .attr("dx", "-10px")
        .attr("dy", "10px")
        .style("text-anchor", "end") //centre la fin du texte au milieu de chaque barre (rect)
        .attr("transform", "rotate(-65)") //effectue une rotation de -65°
        .transition()
        .duration(500)
        .delay(function(d,i){return i *30})
        .attr("font-family", "futura", "Bold")
        .attr("font-size", 10); //style de police de caractère
```

I changed the `dx` and `dy` attribute to pixels because the ems are making the text jump around on refresh. I'm not quite sure how to get the effect you want using ems. Their value changes with font size.

Comment: It totally works now... I don't know what to say, I'm truely gratefull for your help @Mark_M. I'll play Haendel minuet in G minor on my piano in your honor tonight, sir !